# How do I order an HQL query by a property of an object in a collection?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

Let's say I have a Car with a Radio and the Radio has a one-to-many association with Button. What I want is the unique names of all of the buttons in cars made by Ford, sorted by Button name. Given the way our relations are set up, I can't figure out how to do this. Something like:

```
select distinct elements(c.radio.buttons)
from Car c 
where c.make = 'Ford'
order by c.radio.buttons.name
```

The last part is wrong, of course. I'm going to paginate this data so that's why I'm trying to do it entirely in a query.

The answer might involve a join fetch but so far I've had no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HQL would be

```
select distinct button
from Car c join c.radio.buttons button
where c.make = 'Ford'
order by button.name
```

Comment: Since buttons is really another table the join makes perfect sense!